# How can I list files in a directory in Android?

Tags: android, file

I have a folder in root with some files I want to list but the array returns null:

```
String path = getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + "/Files";
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Permissions are granted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list files in an android directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory)

Comment: use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `getenv`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `getenv()`:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Files";
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
```

But a very important note is the `/storage/emulated/0` folder **does not really exist**. It's what might be called a "symbolic link", or, in simpler terms, a reference to where the real data is stored. That's why your array returns null. You'll need to find the actual physical location on your device where it is stored.

Comment: Tried it my friend, nothing changes.. array is still null.

Comment: @Mr.M See my edit, and also make sure your `/Files` directory actually does have files in it.

Comment: This is the path /storage/emulated/0/Files/ it gets

Comment: @Mr.M Take a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399122/how-to-access-storage-emulated-0/49434928

Comment: @Mr.M See my edit again, taking note of the paragraph I added on the `/storage/emulated/0/` folder.

Comment: Ok so the other location i can find it is in /sdcard/Files/ but guess what, still null