# Not Playing Sound in Android 9

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording

I create a record file in **MP3** format, but this file **does not run in Android 9 and above**, **while it runs in Android 7**, another problem is that this file does not open with any other application on the Android phone, but when the file I upload the desired file to the server or run the desired file via USB in Windows. This file will run

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer()
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Audio/20210907144451.mp3"
try {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
           player.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                 .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                 .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                 .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                 .build());
       } else {
             player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       }

       //filePath: /storage/emulated/0/Audio/20210907144451.mp3

       player.setDataSource(filePath);
       player.prepare();
       player.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    LOG(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Error text**

> Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Comment: Did you try removing ````player.prepare()````?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399122/how-to-access-storage-emulated-0/49434928

Comment: yes,and not working.@ElPrimo

Comment: Maybe it is the problem with your filePath. Check this out. If you feel that the path is correct, maybe check the file is corrupted or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android MediaPlayer throwing "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" on 2.1, works on 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2)

Comment: @ElPrimo The file is available ,because I upload the same file to the server and it runs on the server

Comment: Check the question I posted.

Comment: I saw the question that was asked, I did all the things that were said in the answer to the question, but it still can't be done . @ElPrimo

Comment: Maybe try ````player.setDataSource(filePath.toString());````

Comment: **filePath** is of type **String**.@ElPrimo

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that your ````filePath```` is a String

Comment: Your case is strange

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    File directory = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Audio/20210907144451.mp3");
    fis = new FileInputStream(directory);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
}   finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is very strange because the file does not run even other players on the phone, but the same file that is uploaded to the server can be run on the server.

Comment: Yes. It is very strange. Have you tried above code

Comment: yes,did not work. file format: **mp3** or **wav**

Comment: very strange case

Comment: is the file on sdcard, or on internal storage?

Comment: internal storage